# How to Deploy a Cypress Project on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, deployment, cypress

I Have a Cypress Project and i want to deploy on Firebase to run my tests from there.
Is that possible?

Is there a chance to run my project on Firebase like Cypress Cloud CI?

I've already created a Firebase project and followed the instructions (firebase install, firebase int, firebase deploy etc) but when i deploy the project and enter in the website i receive a message on webpage:
"Welcome
Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!"